# LightDM Animations

Tags: lightdm, unity-greeter, animations, pantheon

is there a way to port lightdm lock/unlock fade animation on other greeters? I'm thinking about making a port of the animations on pantheon-greeter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The fade animation is done inside Unity - no greeter is actually used for screen locking. There is not an easy method of doing cross-fades when using a greeter - the switch between session and the greeter is done by switching VTs so neither is aware of each other.